# Using weather apis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

I want to create a simple webpage that pulls tide results from [wunderground.com](http://wunderground.com).
Nothing seems to show up though. I inserted the `load` function so that something shows up when the page loads and then work from there (stylizing my site) but nothing other than my title seems to show up.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<h1>Tide High/Low</h1>
<section id="fetch">
  <div id="tweets"></div>

<style>
body {
  background: #00CCFF;
}

h1 { 
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;

}

#search {
  font-size: 15px;
  left: 200px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #00CCFF;
  margin-left: 275px;

}
</style>

<script>
$("#tweets").load("http://api.wunderground.com/api/961d546ea36a6968/tide.json",
    function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
      if(statusTxt=="success")
          alert("External content loaded successfully!");
      if(statusTxt=="error")
          alert("wuddup: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
});

function getWeather(callback) {
  var weather = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/961d546ea36a6968/tide.json';
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: weather,
    success: callback
  });


getWeather(function (data) {
  console.log('weather data received');
  console.log(data.list[0].weather[0].description); 
  console.log(data.list[0].weather[0].main);  
});

</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/775KZ/
everything looks nice here, no? whats the problem?

Comment: I need to use an api and the 'loaded' function is not displaying what i pulled from wunderground.com

Answer (score 0):

For starters your `getWeather` function declaration is missing the closing `}`. Once that's fixed, it at least fails in a more or less expected manner. (You also have an unclosed `<section>` tag and an empty `<script>` tag, but those aren't really issues, yet).

You should look into what linting tools are available for whatever your development environment is, or using an IDE that has one built into it. Alternatively you can check your javascript online using something like [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/), but obviously it's much easier if you can do so right in your coding environment itself.

You should also familiarize yourself with the debugging tools available for your preferred browser; personally I find the [Chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) indispensable, but pretty much all the browsers have similar tools available.